# Change line when using numpy.savetxt

Tags: python, numpy

When this code in MAC it can work well, but I copy this code to my other computer(windows system), the result is not my want.

Anyone know why?

```
a = [[1349, 1411, 1378, 1434, 1309, 1301, 1295, 1528, 1226, 1332]]
np.savetxt("Q1_ans.txt", a, fmt="%d", delimiter="\n")
```

The result is

```
1349 1411 1378 1434 1309 1301 1295 1528 1226 1332
```

but I want the result to look like the following :

```
1349 

1411 

1378 

1434 

1309 

1301 

1295 

1528 

1226 

1332
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows uses `\r\n` for line endings, while MAC only uses `\n`. This is a [common problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Common_problems) with text files on MAC and Windows.

To solve this, use `\r\n` as `delimiter`, e.g.

```
a = [[1349, 1411, 1378, 1434, 1309, 1301, 1295, 1528, 1226, 1332]]
np.savetxt("Q1_ans.txt", a, fmt="%d", delimiter="\r\n")
```

Comment: How do I do the contrary ? I don't want the empty space between the lines

Comment: Change the delimiter.